# How to get sum of array element values in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have a file with a list of strings:

```
 002.5005.200
 030000050550
 4040004002.2
```

I would like to find the sum of the numbers that make us these strings. I could split each line into an array then loop through each element and add it together. However, is there a more easier way to do this?

Desired Output:

```
 7.7
 18
 14.2
```

Comment: How do you want your program to know you want to add up `2.5` and `5.2`, not `2.5005` and `.2`, `3, 5, 5 and 5` not `3, 50 and 55`? Is the 0 character a separator every time?

Comment: Sorry, no, the 0 will be represented by 0.0. The numbers are formatted with a single decimal point. So in fact, the first line would look more like this: 0.00.02.50.00.05.20.00.0

Comment: So you'll never have to add `1.01` for example? Seems really weird design

Comment: Well, there will be instance when a number like 15.0 would occur

Comment: Then isn't `030000050550` mean `3,5 and 55` ? whereas you show as `3,5,5,5`

Answer (score 3):

**`test.pl`**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<>) {
    my @nums = $_ =~ /([1-9](?:\.[0-9])?)/g;
    my $sum = 0;
    map { $sum += $_ } @nums;
    print "$sum\n";
}
```

**Test**

```
$ cat file
002.5005.200
030000050550
4040004002.2
$ ./test.pl file
7.7
18
14.2
```

---

Or `perl` **one liner**

```
perl -lne '$sum=0; map { $sum += $_ } $_ =~ /([1-9](?:\.[0-9])?)/g; print $sum;' file
```

Comment: perlcritic whined about using "map" here, gave message: "map" used in void context at line 59, column 5.  Use a "for" loop instead.  (Severity: 3). That would look like the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $x = '002.5005.200';
my $sum = 0;
foreach( split '0', $x ) { $sum += $_ }
print "$sum\n";
```

Outputs 7.7

Comment: Would that work for 5.05.015.00.00.02.5 (which is 5,5,15,0,0,2.5)?